# Seaborn lmplot/regplot no fit for logistic: All-NaN slice encountered

Tags: python, seaborn, logistic-regression, statsmodels

(Moved to https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/554136/seaborn-lmplot-regplot-no-fit-for-logistic-all-nan-slice-encountered)

I am trying to create a regression plot for some data using lmplot of Seaborn. However, Seaborn does not plot the regression line, only the points are plotted and I get an error which I don't understand:

> ~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/statsmodels/genmod/families/links.py:187:
> RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp   t = np.exp(-z)
> ~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/lib/nanfunctions.py:1395:
> RuntimeWarning: All-NaN slice encountered   result =
> np.apply_along_axis(_nanquantile_1d, axis, a, q,

While using the 'tips'-dataset I found out that this errors seems to appear if both sets of the data are perfectly separated (See image below). *(I know separating the same value you are plotting the logistic regression against makes no sense, but it produces a dataset similar to the one I have)*

Here is some code to reproduce, modified from https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.regplot.html

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

tips["big_tip"] = tips.total_bill > 20
tips = tips.head(30)

sns.lmplot(x='total_bill',y='big_tip',data=tips, logistic=True)

plt.show()
```

and the resulting image, where I expected to see the regression line:
[image]

Python 3.9.7
Seaborn 0.11.2
Numpy 1.21.1

Comment: The logistics regression need `statsmodels`.  Maybe there is a problem with that library?  It could also be helpful to show the complete error trace to get a better idea where the error originates.

Comment: The error trace is complete, I only changed my home folder name to ~

Comment: Interestingly, `tips["big_tip1"] = (tips.tip / tips.total_bill) > .175` works and `tips["big_tip2"] = tips.total_bill > 20` does not

Comment: Yes, when using the other calculation (tip/bill > .175) both sets are overlapping. Using the later (>20) they are separated perfectly. This seems to be causing an issue

Comment: so this is seems like a logistic regression question, which might be better suited to https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Copied it to SE: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/554136/seaborn-lmplot-regplot-no-fit-for-logistic-all-nan-slice-encountered

Comment: @JohanC Removing the 'head' does not change anything, it then uses 244 values and still gives the same error+ result

Comment: See also [PerfectSeparationError: Perfect separation detected, results not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53041669/error-perfectseparationerror-perfect-separation-detected-results-not-availab) and [Getting "Perfect separation detected, results not available" while building the Logistic Regression model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61173135/getting-perfect-separation-detected-results-not-available-while-building-the)

Comment: Yes almost certainly some bootstrap samples are perfectly separated. You can turn bootstrapping off (`ci=None`), although then you won't get the error bars on the regression line.